# C BlackJack compiles but Segmentation Faults

Tags: c, enums, int

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <time.h>
 #include <getopt.h>


typedef enum {Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades} suit_t;
typedef enum {Ace = 1, Two = 2, Three = 3, Four = 4, Five = 5, Six = 6, Seven = 7, Eight = 8, Nine = 9, Ten = 10, Jack = 10, Queen = 10, King = 10} face_t;

typedef struct card_t
{
        suit_t suit;
        face_t face;
} card;

typedef struct stack_t
{
    card_t deck[52];
    int size;
} stack_h;

void deck_init(stack_h *stack);
int main()
{
        stack_h stack;
        int entry;
        printf("Welcome to BlackJack by CodeHero\n");
        fflush ( stdout );
        printf("Enter 1 to Continue or press 2 to Exit\n");
        fflush ( stdout );
        scanf("%d", &entry);
        fflush ( stdin );

        switch ( entry )
        {
                case 1:

                        deck_init ( &stack );
                        deck_show ( &stack );
                        break;
                case 2:
                        printf("Exitting\n");
                        fflush ( stdout );
                        exit( 1 );
                        break;
        }
}

 void deck_init(stack_h *stack)
 {
        for (int i = Ace; i <= King; ++i)
        {
                for (int j = Clubs; j <= Spades; j++)
                {
                         stack->deck[stack->size].face = i;
                         stack->deck[stack->size].suit = j;
                         stack->size++;
                }
        }
}

void deck_show (stack_h *stack)
{
    int x, i ,j;
    printf("%d Cards in the deck. ", stack -> size);
    for (i = 0; i< 13; i++)
    {
      for(j=0; j < 4; j++)
      {
                printf("%d of %d\n", i, j);
       }
     }
}
```

What I am trying to do is fill the deck with cards and then display all the cards to make sure that the filling of the deck is working, but when I compile it says I have no errors then I go to running the program and it gets all the way to where it says stack->deck[stack->size].face = i; then segmentation faults. I dont really know what I need to do with this since I believe it should work. I have tried changing it from being a pointer to just a regular style stack.deck sorta technique but that came to the same problem. I think it may have an issue to due with the 'enum' not being an int and it does not want to increment an 'enum' or something like that, maybe anyways.

Comment: Ctrl+F "malloc" return nothing in your code : where do you allocate stack ?

Comment: @georgesl Up in my stack_t structure I have card_t deck[52] that's where I've allocated it.

Comment: my issue is this line : "stack_h *stack;" . It hints that you want to use a heap-allocated memory to hold your instance called 'stack'. However, dynamically allocation in C has to be manually done using the malloc function. Your 'stack' variable is just a dangling pointer.

Comment: BTW, where is `stack_h` defined? I see only `stack_t`.

Comment: stack_h *stack; this is in main and should be declaring it unless I'm wrong.

Comment: This didn't compile.  `stack_h` isn't defined, and you're missing a ; in the `stack_t` declaration.

Comment: `stack_h` is a type. Where is it's definition?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I messed up there when I declared the stack_t I meant for it to be stack_h which I changed and everything should be in order. My bad when I was getting the code over here from my compiler.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have it to where stack_t becomes stack_h then later inside of main I have it stack_h *stack. Which should have it as a pointer allowing me to use what I have down below.

Comment: Ok, you might want to add a semicolon after `stack_h`. But having a pointer is not enough to do whatever you do down below. This pointer has to point to some allocated memory. In you case it is just uninitialized (having some random value, or NULL).

Comment: @EugeneSh. Okay. I have done that and ran it through my compiler and I receive no errors. But it still does what I said. I haven't ever used malloc nor do I know how.

Comment: So you might want to show us the updated code. I guess it is a good time to learn how to use `malloc`. Pretty handy stuff.

Comment: @EugeneSh. So I've updated it to how was told to declare my stack_h, the updated code is above.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I've seen malloc used sometimes but I don't fully understand it

Comment: @MikeHousky I've made those changes but I don't know exactly how to use malloc, the changes made compiled correctly I guess all thats left is to use malloc which I don't really know what yo do with.

Comment: @EugeneSh. So you are saying that up in my struct where I have size declared I set it to 0 which in code int size = 0; ?

Comment: I guess, putting `stack->size=0;` in the beginning of your `deck_init` will be enough (see the update about `deck_show` as well).

Comment: @EugeneSh. For deck_show () I fixed the format error I changed the x to an I so that I'd have more cards instead of repeats but it only counts 40 cards and that's it and also it doesn't make the suits correctly so I think maybe doing the same for suits or setting j to read every 13 cards and put it into that suit

Comment: `j` is still uninitialized.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I just initialized it sorry for the delay on that. I was testing but I changed The j to read in each suit and each card by changing I < 13; is that okay to do?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes :D I just need it to display the actual name Ace instead of 0 and so on so forth.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Do you think that if I create a const char* {}with the names inside and then take it down to my print that'd work?

Comment: Look here: http://www.lemoda.net/c/c-string-array-initialization/

Comment: @EugeneSh. Alright thank you very much for the help! I have resolved what I needed at the moment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stack` structure is not allocated anywhere, and you are attempting to access unallocated `stack` pointer's fields in your `deck_init` (and later). You might want to allocate it dynamically using `malloc` or declare `stack_t` variable in your `main` statically, and work with pointer to it.  
Upd( After the edit) : The `stack->size` is not initialized anywhere as well. It should be initialized to zero prior the use in `deck_init`. 
Upd2: In `deck_show` you are attempting to print uninitialized variables `i,j`, and also passing the two variables, while only one formatting modifier in `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allocate a stack in `main()` and pass it's pointer to functions you call, use:

```
stack_t stack; /* or stack_h if that's your new type name */
```

Then use `&stack` to pass it's pointer to a function that takes a stack pointer:

```
deck_init(&stack): /* for example */
```

Your `stack_t *stack;` declaration creates a pointer only, and does not give that pointer a value.

If this was a large structure, or if there were going to be many of them, then you might want to use `malloc()` to allocate them at run-time, but I'd wait and add that complexity later--if it's even needed.